How are these two definitions of connection on a vector bundle equivalent?

Definition 1 states that a connection is a map:
$$
\nabla : \Gamma(E) \to \Gamma(T^*M \otimes E) = \Omega^1(M; E),
$$
which satisfies the Leibniz rule:
$$
\nabla(f s) = df \otimes s + f \nabla s,
$$
for any $f \in C^\infty(M)$ and $s \in \Gamma(E)$.

Definition 2 states that a connection is a map:
$$
\nabla : \mathfrak{X}(M) \times \Gamma(E) \to \Gamma(E),
$$
with the covariant derivative $\nabla_X Y$ satisfying linearity in $X$ and the Leibniz rule:
$$
\nabla_X(f Y) = f \nabla_X Y + (X f) Y,
$$
for any vector field $X \in \mathfrak{X}(M)$, $Y \in \Gamma(E)$, and $f \in C^\infty(M)$.


I am struggling to understand why these two definitions are equivalent. I am familiar with definition 2, but then I found definition 1 and can't figure one how they are the same. Domains and codomains look different (no vector field as input in definition 1), I don't see why $\Gamma(T^*M \otimes E) = \Omega^1(M; E)$ either.  In  $df \otimes s + f \nabla s$ the fact that one term is a tensor product make me think that $df \otimes s$ aand  $f \nabla s$ don't even require the same number of inputs since I think  $df \otimes s$ should be "eating" two arguments as input (on for df  the other for s)while $f \nabla s$ only one (it's an element of $\Omega^1(M; E)$ , I mean one-forms "eat" only one vector right?)

$(\omega\otimes s)(v)=\omega(v)s$.

@TedShifrin when working with tensor products I am only familiar with this example $(dx \otimes dy) (\partial_x;\partial_y)=dx(\partial_x)dy(\partial_y)$. So I think a tensor product requires two arguments. I don't see how you would only input one argument to the tensor product

A section of $T^*M\otimes T^*M$ is different from a section of $T^*M\otimes E$ for a general vector bundle $E$. It's $T^*M$ that eats elements of $TM$; $E$ eats no one. Indeed, you need to understand why a section of $T^*M\otimes E$ is an $E$-valued $1$-form. You probably need to study up on tensor products and tensor products of general vector bundles a bit more.

See here

This is a common point of confusion. See previous questions here, here, and here.
